# How to apply PySpark Function that creates columns to a grouped / paritioned dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, group-by

I feel like I've missed something simple here but I'm trying to find a way to do something similar to the applyInPandas method except where the function is still using pyspark. For example if I have a data frame as below:

```
input_df: DataFrame = spark.createDataFrame([
            ("test_1", "test_file_1", "ewqeq"),
            ("test_1", "test_file_1", "ewqeq"),
            ("test_1", "test_file_1", "ewqeq"),
            ("test_1", "test_file_1", "ewqeq"),
            ("test_1", "test_file_1", "ewqeq"),
            ("test_1", "test_file_1", "ewqeq"),
            ("test_2", "test_file_2", "ewqeq"),
            ("test_2", "test_file_2", "ewqeq"),
            ("test_2", "test_file_2", "ewqeq"),
            ("test_2", "test_file_2", "ewqeq"),
            ("test_2", "test_file_2", "ewqeq"),
            ("test_2", "test_file_2", "ewqeq")
        ], schema=["column_a", "column_b", "test_string_col"])
```

and I now want to groupby column_a and column_b and then apply a function that generates new column(s) depending on what's in column_a and column_b e.g

```
def some_pyspark_func(a, b, df):
    if (a == "test_1") and (b == "test_file_1"):
        return df.withColumn("output_1", lit("Test")).withColumn("output_2", lit("Test2"))
    return df.withColumn("output_1", lit("Test3"))

def my_func(df):
    a = df.collect()[0].column_a
    b = df.collect()[0].column_b
    return some_pyspark_func(a, b, df)
```

The number or rows in the data will stay the same and where one of the groups returns columns not in the other we just want to populate this with nulls in the other grouped dataframe.

I tried using the applyInPandas method here but because the function is in pyspark and the workers dont have access to the spark context I can't create the spark dataframe from the pandas dataframe on the worker to pass into the function.

Comment: try `when().otherwise()`. you situation is of SQL's case when, and looks like you don't need a group by

Comment: Thanks, while I could replace the function with a when().otherwise() in this example, some_pyspark_func that I defined here was purely as a minimum reproducible example, in my actual case I have a lot of complex logic that goes on here so I need to call it as is (some_pyspark_func(a, b, df)).

Comment: the best way to make us understand your problem would be to share an MRE that "closely" resembles your problem statement. would it be possible to do that or share high level steps? in most cases, an user defined function isn't required at all and spark funcs can be readily used (with extra steps).

Answer (score 0):

You can try to split into multiple Dataframes using filter/where and mutually exclusive filtering criteria like:

```
df_1 = df.where("column_a == 'test_1'").where("column_b== 'test_file_1'")
df_2 = df.where("column_a == 'test_2'").where("column_b== 'test_file_2'")
```

Then apply transformations on each Dataframe separately and finally do

```
df = df_1.unionByName(df_2)
```

I would encourage you to use .when().otherwise() as @samkart suggested, but if the logic differs much depending on values in column_a and column_b, is complex and long as you are saying, then it makes sense to use the method I described above. It most likely will perform worse, but with logic complex enough will be better readable and maintainable code.